# Computation Of full range fourier series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-series

Question:
Given that $f(x)=(x−4)^2\forall x\in[0,4]$. For each of the following questions, define a periodic extension function of $f(x)$ and sketch its graph on the interval $[−8,8]$.

Determine the full-range Fourier series expansion corresponding to $f(x)$.

My answer :

Full range series: $p=4,l=2$

$\begin{align*}
a_0&=\frac1L\int\limits_{-L}^Lf(x)\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac22\int\limits_0^4\left[x^2-8x+16\right]\mathrm dx\\
&=\left[\frac13x^3-4x^2+16x\right]\Big|^4_0\\
a_0&=64/3
\end{align*}$

$\begin{align*}
a_n&=\frac1L\int\limits_{-L}^Lf(x)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}L\right)\mathrm dx\\
&=\int\limits_0^4x^2\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}2\right)\mathrm dx-8\int\limits_{0}^{4}x\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}2\right)\mathrm dx+16\int\limits_{0}^{4}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}2\right)\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac22\left[\frac{32}{n^2\pi^2}-8(0)+16\left(\frac{2}{n\pi}\sin\left(\frac{nx\pi}{2}\right)\right)\Big|^4_0\right]\\
a_n&=\frac{16}{n^2\pi^2}
\end{align*}$

Is my fourier series right ?

Comment: Where are the "following questions"?

Comment: A quick calculation gives me $a_n = \frac{64}{n^2 \pi^2}$.

Comment: sorry.Now i already edited. Could yo check now Christian blatter

Comment: no, you still have $L = 2$ in the denominator of $\cos$. Those need to be "4"'s instead.

Comment: why l need to be 4. The period is 4 right. Therefore p=2L and L=2. Because the interval is [0,4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you need $L = 4$ (the length of the original interval), not 2 (as it appears in the denominator of $\cos$). Also, the new function will (probably) have a period of 8, though it seems like there are some specifics of the problem missing (are you supposed to define even periodic extensions, odd periodic extensions, etc.?).